# Why doesn't this code cause an infinite loop?

Tags: smalltalk

Let's say I define a new class, and I override class:

```
class
   ^self class.
```

And then I run:

```
var:=NewClass new.
Transcript show:(var class);cr.
```

Why doesn't this code cause an infinite loop?

The runtime class is `NewClass`, so how come the code calls the class defined in `Object`, and not the class defined in `NewClass`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Smalltalk implementations may implement certain shortcuts for special messages. You didn't specify your Smalltalk implementation, but most likely it has a special bytecode to retrieve the class of an object. When the Smalltalk VM encounters that bytecode, it does not really send the message `class` to the receiver, so your method is never invoked and the infinite recursion does not happen. The Smalltalk compiler will emit that special bytecode instead of the bytecode(s) for a message send if it sees that you use `class`.

The same typically happens with `ifTrue: ifFalse:`, instead of compiling message sends to the receiver (boolean) object, the Smalltalk compiler will emit conditional jumps in the bytecode of the "calling" method.

To get such an infinite loop, you could try with `perform: #class` both in your script and in the implementation of `NewClass>>class`.

```
class
   ^ self perform: #class
```

Comment: Funnily enough, when I run the code in debug mode I indeed see the infinite loop - which makes it even more peculiar.

Comment: That's because the debugger simulates the VM, or rather the interpretation of the bytecodes. It may implement the class bytecode by actually sending the class message.